# Why do I get NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' …?

Tags: android, date, calendar, android-calendar

CODE:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {

        String message = chatList.get(position).getMessage();
        String timeStamp = chatList.get(position).getTimestamp();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(timeStamp));
        String dataTime = format("MMMM d, h:mm a", cal).toString();


        holder.timeTv.setText(dateTime);
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long 
java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: `Long.getLong(timeStamp)` – You do not want the `getLong()` method there. That's not doing what you think it is. Perhaps you want `parseLong()` instead.

Comment: OK, you edited that, but now the Exception message doesn't match up with that code. `parseLong()` returns a primitive `long`.

Comment: You are getting `timestamp` as null. So kindly wrap up it with null check.

Comment: `String timeStamp = chatList.get(position).getTimestamp();` this code is ok? Mean timestamp has only numeric value?

Comment: I was watching this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MblszhqIWI8&list=PLs1bCj3TvmWmM-qN3FsCuPTTX-29I8Gh7&index=12) and here the code is working.

Comment: It seems that `chatList.get(position).getTimestamp()` returns `null`. You may want [to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Yes, I've been trying with different options but unfortunately still not working.

Answer (score 0):

debug your code / print logs and make sure you not getting null value of **getTimestamp** and try this it will work

```
   String dataTime = String.valueOf(format("MMMM d, h:mm a", cal));
```

Comment: Still gives error:Process: com.example.bkkapp, PID: 10207
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:553)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:632)
        at com.example.bkkapp.adapters.AdapterChat.onBindViewHolder(AdapterChat.java:75)
        at com.example.bkkapp.adapters.AdapterChat.onBindViewHolder(AdapterChat.java:32)

Comment: Please try putting hardcoded "1568117980" as the timestamp and see if you still get the null exception

Comment: Hey Italy Feldman. Hardcoded option works! But then how could I set the time (the hardcoded long) to  timestamp string?

Comment: @MolnarAttila If hardcoded works it means your still getting null when not hardcoded.. I didn't quite get the question in your comment if you could elaborate on it. Anyway first thing first, make sure you don't get a null value from the getTimestamp() method.

Comment: @Italy Feldman Yes I got it what you mean. Basically the timestamp is added to the FirebaseDatabase and now I'm trying to figuring out, how to get it back that time.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I used the following code and it worked for me.

```
private static DateTimeFormatter timestampFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
        .toFormatter();

private static DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
```

then in onBindViewHolder, I added the following snippet:

```
 Instant inst;
        if (timeStamp == null) {
            inst = Instant.now();
        } else {
            inst = Instant.from(timestampFormatter.parse(timeStamp));
       }
        String dateTime = inst.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dtf);
```